# How to make /views/shared/_layout.cshtml in Razor site return 404 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to have this url (/views/shared/_layout.cshtml) generate a 404 response code & show my custom 404 page. It currently generates this 500 error and stack trace:

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: **Files with leading underscores ("_") cannot be served.**

Stack Trace: 
[HttpException (0x80004005): Files with leading underscores ("_") cannot be served.]
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.GetRouteLevelMatch(String pathValue, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions, VirtualPathFactoryManager virtualPathFactoryManager) +291
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.MatchRequest(String pathValue, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions, VirtualPathFactoryManager virtualPathFactoryManager) +441
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.DoPostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +222
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +146
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +220
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +120

Comment: Hey did you figure this out? I am trying to fix the same issue

Comment: Is directory listing enabled for some reason?

Comment: If anyone has this issue with Sitecore, you're probably missing the Sitecore.Mvc.config file from your includes folder.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following setting in your `Views\web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: This is already in the default blank MVC 3 template which I am using and the problem still exists. Here is the sample nuget pkg / site I am trying to fix it for: https://github.com/andrewdavey/NotFoundMvc/

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code that throws the exception: it happens because the WebPageHttpModule has hooked up a PostResolveRequestCache handler which tries to resolve the route. It then detects an invalid path and barfs.

Maybe if you are able to register your own IHttpModule before WebPageHttpModule, you can act on the request before the default PostResolveRequestCache handler does.

Yet another option might be to hook into the Application_Error event, and then investigate the exception and return a 404 if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS in integrated mode, perhaps block at the server level:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <!--- any others here --->
    <handlers>
      <!--- any others here --->
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I am using the default blank MVC 3 template and the BlockedViewHandler is already mapped to "*" in the Views\web.config and the System.Web.WebPages is still processing it and throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case anyone has the same problem, you can try this solution.

The problem happens because the file name starts with an underscore (which causes HTTP 500 to be returned). To solve the problem, you should rename the file to remove the underscore. Now you should start getting HTTP 404 as long as you have webpages:Enabled set to false in web.config.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, still you got a right answer or not.

Today I just came to know that: ASP.NET Web Pages are having a property like -

**Preventing Files from Being Browsed**

> With ASP.NET, files with a name that starts with an underscore cannot
>   be browsed from the web.
>
> If you want to prevent your content blocks or layout files from being
>   viewed by your users, rename the files to:
>
> _header.cshtm
>
> _footer.cshtml
>
> _Layout.cshtml

Link to view this info is: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_layout.asp.

Keeping this in mind, underscore(_) in starting of any file name should be used to secure your partial files from browse in web.

I think now reason is clear to you.

Comment: Egads... Please don't use or recommend W3Schools... it is packed with bad information.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this issue and i found the correct answer here:

[The layout page "{path}" could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145636/the-layout-page-path-could-not-be-found)

Its a stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a missing Sitecore.Mvc.config which caused the problem as proposed by [Timm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130734/timm)