# Why wouldn't IIS be using my _ViewStart and _Layout files when I load a View?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created an MVC 3 app using a pretty standard setup.  My _ViewStart file specifies that _Layout should be used and my CSS and JS files are included in the _Layout file.

When I debug and navigate to /Home/Index, my page looks exactly as I would expect.  My site is styled properly and all of my javascript includes are present.

When I publish this site to an IIS server, and then navidate to /Home/Index, the site loads, but the page has no styles or javascript.  When I view the source, I can see that all IIS did was serve Index.cshtml directly, without first combining it with _Layout.  I can't figure out why it works in debug, but not in IIS.  Could it be a permissions issue?

**SOLVED**

I submitted my solution below.  I will accept it once the 48 hour waiting period is over.

Comment: Is the razor parsed or is it included in the output? If it is then your website is probably pointing to the wrong folder for the web application.

Comment: I assume you confirmed that your `_ViewStart.cshtml` file was present in the published location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boom, solved it.

My application pool was running as the wrong user.  That particular user did not have read access to my application's directory.

It was very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145636/the-layout-page-path-could-not-be-found), but I was not getting any sort of error.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility for not seeing styles is that you hardcoded the urls for your custom javascript and CSS files, like this:

```
<link href="/Content/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

instead of using url helpers:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/MyStyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

so that the virtual directory that you have hosted your application in IIS is no longer taken into account.

If you cannot see the contents of _Layout.cshtml make sure that it has been deployed in IIS along with `_ViewStart.cshtml`. There is no reason for IIS not serving those files.

Comment: That's a good idea to check for virtual directory issues, but my <link> and <script> tags aren't being processed because they are in the _Layout file and the _Layout code is never being run.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS7 by any chance? If yes, make sure you have the static content services enabled:

http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/05/23/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732612(WS.10).aspx