# ASP.NET MVC3 deployment - _layout master page not found in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The layout page “{path}” could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145636/the-layout-page-path-could-not-be-found)

I published the site to local IIS server using "Filesystem Profile". After hitting through local url from IIS, web site does not find master page e.g. "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"

The same website runs perfectly from the vs-2010 on same machine.

Comment: Please let us know what OS you are running and what version of IIS you've deployed to. Also, is the app pool set for .NET 4.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Have you verified that the file is in fact in the folder where you deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks buddies for reply.

Actually I was trying to setup on Win-2008-R2 with IIS 7.5.

There was an issue with permissions. The site is configured with app pool .NET 4.0 which runs under NetworkService account. Giving acccess right to "NetworkService" for website  resolved the issue.

Another question addressing the same issue: 
[The layout page "{path}" could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145636/the-layout-page-path-could-not-be-found)

Another link for configuration:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Comment: This answer has already been reviewed by a moderator.