# IIS 7 Not find the _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, iis-7

I am having a problem with a MVC application. When I publish it, I have the follow error:

```
The layout page "~/Views/Login/_LayoutLogin.cshtml" could not be found at the following path: "~/Views/Login/_LayoutLogin.cshtml".
```

Comment: Yes, in the same path. I think that it can be about some server permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem once.

I figure out that it was an IIS permission problem. I went to the Application Pool and to the Authentication options. Then I edited the Anonymous Authentication Credentials to "Application pool identity"

Here is an answer in another post that have a better explanation about the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6156675/2430118

Pedro